# Ubuntu 12.04 Dual Monitor No Log In Screen on Resume

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, resume

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with Radian HD 7770 display card driving two monitors.  When I resume from sleep its a 50:50 chance that the login prompt will show up while the other monitor is blank until I log in.  When it doesn't I've tried right clicking the mouse and Fn F12 Fn to get the screen with the log in prompt to turn on with no affect.  Until recently I was getting the login prompt reliably.  Last year I was able to get the login to show up by turning one display off and on.  Now nothing works and I can't put my system to sleep while I have work open.

I am running AMD Catalyst 2.21,  RandR V 1.3, and lspci | grep VGA comes back with "VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770 GHz Edition]"

Comment: I'm still having this issue.  Thought maybe it might be how the mouse wakes the system up, so I have tried clicking the center scroll button to wake up the mouse and system.  Worked twice.  Did not work this morning.  What else should I do?  I hate having to do a hard shut down and reboot.